# integral of cdf function

Tags: calculus, probability

[image]

Could anyone please help me how has this integral of cdf been solved?

(M is median)

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. Please considering editing your post. You can find information on how to that here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference
Also, what have you done so far?

Comment: Are you familiar with integration by parts?

Comment: It follows from integration by parts and the definition of the CDF in terms of the pdf (the last integral should be of help here).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is an application of integration by parts using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus $F'(x)=f(x)$ and the subsitution $\alpha=x$. Consider the formula for integration by parts

$$\int u~dv=uv-\int v~du$$

by setting $u=F(\alpha)$ and $dv=1\cdot d\alpha$ therefore $du=f(\alpha)d\alpha$ and $v=\alpha$ followed by $\alpha=x$ within your given integral leads to

$$\int_m^a F(\alpha)d\alpha=[\alpha F(\alpha)]_m^a-\int_m^a \alpha f(\alpha)d\alpha\stackrel{\alpha=x}{=}aF(a)-mF(m)-\int_m^a xf(x)dx$$

Comment: I appreciate that.

Comment: In this case mark my answer as "accepted" to show that you are satisfied with the given one and so other users can see that your question is answered. Further you could als given it an upvote :)